# Cisco ACL Entries

Tags: cisco-ios, cisco-nx-os

I have a cisco 4500x and n5k-5672up and in their datasheet mentioned that we can have "Security ACL Entries (1K=1024) 128K (64K ingress and 64K in egress) Shared with QoS" for 4500x and " Support for up to 4000 access control list (ACL) entries" for n5k-5672up so my question is that:

1. I can have different acl names but totally they should have 128000 lines for 4500x or 4000 lines for n5k-5672 and I can assign the acls to unlimited SVIs or interfaces?
2. for example "10 permit ip 192.168.10.5/32 any" count as 1 line and entries?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I would understand it like that as well. "128K" means 131,072 ACEs though, 65,536 for ingress and egress each. ;-)

Comment: so it's not important that how many ACL names do you have or you assigned them to how many interfaces or SVIs? the important thing is the number of entries/lines in each ACL , right?

Comment: Generally, yes. I'm not too familiar with those switches, so I was just commenting, not answering.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct -- the ACL doesn't consume additional TCAM space as you apply it to more interfaces.

Comment: each line count as 1 entery ? if I use /29 , /28 or .. in the line? in juniper if you use /29 it will use more tcam space.

Comment: @Blackmetal That's peculiar - could you provide a link to the docs?

Comment: https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB30953&actp=METADATA

Comment: @Blackmetal Can't find that information there, apart from using 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.1.0/24 *separately* instead of 10.0.0.0/23 *aggregated* consumes twice the TCAM amount.